# Cannot connect to SPO site with SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, authentication, connection

I cannot connect to a SharePoint Online site from SharePoint Designer 2013.

When I try to connect to the site, it asks me to log-in, however, when I enter my credentials, I get this error:
[image]

I'm sure the details are correct.

The account has a SharePoint Admin role in O365 and is a site collection owner.

All the other tenants I manage are working fine, as this one used to as well.

I tried clearing the browser and SPD caches, also re-installing the SPD 2013, but that didn't fix it.

I assume this is an authentication issue, but I can't figure this out...
The SPD settings in central admin and site collection settings are all fine as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have MFA enabled ? If yes, create and use the app password.

Comment: @GautamSheth no, it hasn't...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was related to **two-factor** authentication. I solve it by generating *app password* on page https://portal.office.com/account. When you generate this unique password phrase then just use it instead you original password.

Answer (score 0):

Please troubleshoot your issue as following:

1. Go to SharePoint admin center ->settings-> Make sure you select "Allow users to run custom script on personal sites under Custom Script".
2. Use another username and password to login and check if the issue exists.
3. Go to Control Panel->Credential Manager->clear Windows credentials.

Comment: Done all of that and everything else I could find... Will probably need to open a ticket with Microsoft :)